# indexOf (String str) - equals string to other string

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to write method that will chek "String str" on other string, and return the index that the str starts.

That's sound like homework, and it is some of homework but for my use to learn for a test...

i've tried:

```
public int IndexOf (String str) {

   for (i= 0;i<_st.length();i++)
   {
        if (_st.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i)) {
            i++;
            if (_st.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
   }
   return -1;
 }
```

but i dont get the right return. why? i'm on the right way or don't even close?

Comment: Where do you define `_st`? Is it a global variable? Shouldn't the function be self-contained, i.e., all variables passed as arguments?

Comment: any problem in using default `str.indexOf("s");`. And why you are checking same condition twice?

Comment: @Hary Joy - i need to write indexOf by my-self. @Emil - everything define well, i didn't include all the class here... only that part.

Comment: @Emil: Some people use `_` as a prefix for member variables (fields). I detest that sort of naming convention, but I guess @Bside's professor thinks otherwise.

Comment: @Bside, as Emil said, there is no need to use global variables, _st should be either argument of IndexOf(), or function field variable

Comment: @bbaja: We don't know that `_st` isn't an instance member of the class to which `IndexOf` belongs. My guess is it is. (I always use `this.`, but it *is* optional in Java.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid, you are not close.

Here's what you have to do:

- Loop on the characters of the string (the one *on* which you are supposed to do an `indexOf`, I will call this the *master*) (you are going this right)
- For every character check whether your other string's character and this character are the same.
- If they are (a potential start of the same sequence) check whether the next characters in the master match with your String to check (You might want to loop through the elements of the string and check one by one).
- If they don't match, continue with the characters in the master string

Something like:

```
Loop master string
for every character (using index i, lets say)
   check whether this is same as first character of the other string
   if it is
      //potential match
      loop through the characters in the child string (lets say using index j)

      match them with the consecutive characters in the master string 
      (something like master[j+i] == sub[j])

       If everything match, 'i' is what you want
       otherwise, continue with the master, hoping you find a match
```

Some other points:

- In java, method names start with a
  lower case letter by *convention*
  (meaning, the compiler won't
  complain, but your fellow programmers
  may). So `IndexOf` should actually be
  `indexOf`
- Having instance variables
  (class level variables) start with a
  `_` (as in `_st`) is not a really good
  practice. If your professor insists,
  you may not have many options, but
  keep this in mind)

Comment: Thank you very much. i'll try that.. but what is important - i understand your mean.

Answer (score 2):

Not really very close, I'm afraid. What that code basically does is check there if the two strings have two characters in the same positions at any point and, if so, returns the index of the second of those characters. E.g., if `_str` is "abcdefg" and `str` is "12cd45", you'll return 3 because they have "cd" in the same place, and that's the index of the "d". At least, that's as near as I can tell what it's actually doing. That's because you're indexing into both strings with the same indexing variable.

To re-write `indexOf`, looking for `str` within `_st`, you have to scan `_st` for the first character in `str` and then check whether the remaining characters match; if not, bump forward one place from where you started checking and continue your scan. (There are optimisations you can do, but that's the essence of it.) So for instance, if you find the first character of `str` at index 4 in `_st` and `str` is six characters long, having found the first character you need to see if the remaining five (`str`'s indexes 1-5 inclusive) match `_st`'s indexes 5-10 inclusive (easiest just to check all six of `str`'s characters against a substring of `_st` starting at 4 and going for six charactesr). If everything matches, return the index at which you found the first character (so, 4 in that example). You can stop scanning at `_st.length() - str.length()` since if you haven't found it starting prior to that point, you're not going to find it at all.

Side point: Don't call the `length` function on every loop. The JIT *may* be able to optimize out the call, but if you know that `_st` won't change during the course of this function (and if you don't know that, you should require it), grab `length()` to a local and then refer to that. And of course, since you know you can stop earlier than `length()`, you'l use a local to remember where you can stop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` for both strings equal, but what you wan't is the first string to always start at 0 unless the character is found is the other string. Then check if the next characters are equal and so on.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code loops through the string being searched and if the characters at position i match, it checks the next position. If the strings match at the next position, you assume that the string str is contained in _st.

What you probably want to do is:

- keep track of whether the whole of str is contained in _st. You could probably check whether the string that you are searching for has length equal to the number of matching characters so far.
- if you do the above then you could get the starting index by subtracting the number of matches so far from the current value of i.

One question:

Why are you not using the built in String.IndexOf() function? Is this assignment meant for you to implement this functionality on your own?

Comment: Yes, i need to write the indexOf() by my-self.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the Oracle Java API Source code does help:

```
   /**
     * Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
     * specified substring. The integer returned is the smallest value
     * <i>k</i> such that:
     * <blockquote><pre>
     * this.startsWith(str, <i>k</i>)
     * </pre></blockquote>
     * is <code>true</code>.
     *
     * @param   str   any string.
     * @return  if the string argument occurs as a substring within this
     *          object, then the index of the first character of the first
     *          such substring is returned; if it does not occur as a
     *          substring, <code>-1</code> is returned.
     */
    public int indexOf(String str) {
    return indexOf(str, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
     * specified substring, starting at the specified index.  The integer
     * returned is the smallest value <tt>k</tt> for which:
     * <blockquote><pre>
     *     k &gt;= Math.min(fromIndex, this.length()) && this.startsWith(str, k)
     * </pre></blockquote>
     * If no such value of <i>k</i> exists, then -1 is returned.
     *
     * @param   str         the substring for which to search.
     * @param   fromIndex   the index from which to start the search.
     * @return  the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
     *          specified substring, starting at the specified index.
     */
    public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) {
        return indexOf(value, offset, count,
                       str.value, str.offset, str.count, fromIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Code shared by String and StringBuffer to do searches. The
     * source is the character array being searched, and the target
     * is the string being searched for.
     *
     * @param   source       the characters being searched.
     * @param   sourceOffset offset of the source string.
     * @param   sourceCount  count of the source string.
     * @param   target       the characters being searched for.
     * @param   targetOffset offset of the target string.
     * @param   targetCount  count of the target string.
     * @param   fromIndex    the index to begin searching from.
     */
    static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
                       char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
                       int fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
            return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
    }
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = 0;
        }
    if (targetCount == 0) {
        return fromIndex;
    }

        char first  = target[targetOffset];
        int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);

        for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
            /* Look for first character. */
            if (source[i] != first) {
                while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
            }

            /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
            if (i <= max) {
                int j = i + 1;
                int end = j + targetCount - 1;
                for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j] ==
                         target[k]; j++, k++);

                if (j == end) {
                    /* Found whole string. */
                    return i - sourceOffset;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```